# Time picker is not getting hours and minutes value correctly

Tags: android

I am facing one issue, i am using time picker to display hours and minutes, User can change the Hours and minutes value upon taping on the hours and minutes field so it will open android keypad to enter new value of hours and minutes but what I observed that sometimes hours value updated properly and sometimes minutes value but at a time only one value is coming properly and other value is 0. I am using timepicker.getCurrenrHour() and getCurrentMinute() methods to get the updated value , but both value are not coming properly.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code :

```
package org.stellent.Sample;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class DateandTime extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private static final int TIME_DIALOG = 1;
Button time;

public void onCreate(Bundle state){
super.onCreate(state);
setContentView(R.layout.timeanddate);

time=(Button)findViewById(R.id.time);

time.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v.equals(time)){
showDialog(TIME_DIALOG);        
}
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();        
switch(id){
case TIME_DIALOG:
return new TimePickerDialog(this,timepicker,cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
}
return null;
}


TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timepicker=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
Log.e("time :",String.valueOf(hourOfDay)+" : "+String.valueOf(minute));
}
};


}
```

Comment: Thanks Surendra, you are superb :), It's working as intended.